# The geometric interpretation

Tags: analysis, integration

In the course of mathematical analysis, there was one problem that i excited to know more about it:
What is the geometric interpretation of
$$ \int_a^b f(x)\,d(\alpha(x)) $$
and $\alpha(x)$ is function in $[a,b]$

Comment: This is a Stiltjes-integral, and you can view $\alpha$ as a scale for the $x$-axis. I've once written this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378621/#378675 answer trying to explain it in simply terms.

Comment: [A Geometric Interpretation of the Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322483) might be of help.

"Bullock, Gregory L. "A geometric interpretation of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral." The American Mathematical Monthly 95.5 (1988): 448-455."

If you do not have access, I can email you the article.

Answer (score 1):

$$d\alpha(x)=\frac{d\alpha}{dx}dx$$

So the integral can be rewritten as follows:

$$\int_a^b{f(x)d\alpha(x)}=\int_a^bf(x)\frac{d\alpha}{dx}dx$$

So a geometric interpretation is, it's the integral of $f(x)$ multiplied by the derivative of $\alpha$. However, this calculation is only valid if $\alpha$ is both continuous and differentiable on $[a,b)$.

Comment: Be carefull, the stiltjes integral is define even if $\alpha(x)$ is not differentiable - e.g., being increasing is sufficient. Also, if $\alpha(x)$ is differentiable except for finitly many points, your formula is *wrong*, even though one might think "hey, it's an integral, finitly many points do not matter". In this case, they do.

Comment: I see...so this wouldn't work for, say, $\alpha(x)=|x|$ on the interval $[-1,1)$?

Comment: For $|x|$ it happens to work I think, but for e.g. $sgn(x)$ it doesn't.

Comment: @fgp $|x|$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$, is that not a problem?

Comment: Not in this case, because the function is continuous there. Thus, there's no "sudden" increase in measure at the point 0, and you therefore may ignore it. In measure-theoretic terms this is because $\{0\}$ is set of measure 0. If $\alpha$ was discontinuous at $0$, $\{0\}$ would no longer have measure zero, and you'd have to handle it. (Note though that your $\alpha$ isn't increasing, so it doesn't actually define a measure. But it defines a *signed* measue)